# AWS Lambda with Spring Boot native 2.7.1 throws error at runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-lambda, spring-cloud-function, spring-native

Trying to run spring cloud function with spring boot in AWS lambda. The lambda errors out at runtime - errors attached below

- Java Version: 11
- Spring Boot: 2.7.1

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.myorg.jobs</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-jobs</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny</builder>
        <spring-boot.version>2.7.1</spring-boot.version>
        <spring-native.version>0.12.1</spring-native.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <wrapper.version>1.0.29.RELEASE</wrapper.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <wrapper.version>1.0.29.RELEASE</wrapper.version>
        <aws-lambda-events.version>3.9.0</aws-lambda-events.version>
        <spring-cloud-function.version>3.2.12</spring-cloud-function.version>
        <com.amazonaws.java-sdk-lambda.version>1.9.22</com.amazonaws.java-sdk-lambda.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <!-- <optional>true</optional> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-lambda</artifactId>
            <version>${com.amazonaws.java-sdk-lambda.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.experimental/spring-native -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-native</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>${builder}</builder>
                        <env>
                            <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
                            <BP_JVM_VERSION>11</BP_JVM_VERSION>
                            <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE_BUILD_ARGUMENTS>--initialize-at-build-time=org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap,org.springframework.util.ClassUtils
                                --trace-class-initialization=org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap,org.springframework.util.ClassUtils</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE_BUILD_ARGUMENTS>
                        </env>
                        <pullPolicy>IF_NOT_PRESENT</pullPolicy>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-native.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-release</id>
            <name>Spring release</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

**SpringBoot Main Application**

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchRestClientAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

import com.myorg.profile.util.DefaultProfileUtil;
import com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.annotation.EnableEncryptableProperties;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEncryptableProperties
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class, ElasticsearchRestClientAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.myorg" })
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = "com.myorg")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.myorg")
@EnableMongoRepositories("com.myorg")
public class SampleJobApplication {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleJobApplication .class);

    private final Environment env;

    public SampleJobApplication(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(SampleJobApplication.class);
        DefaultProfileUtil.addDefaultProfile(app);
        Environment env = app.run(args).getEnvironment();            
    }


    private static void logApplicationStartup(Environment env) {
        String protocol = "http";
        if (env.getProperty("server.ssl.key-store") != null) {
            protocol = "https";
        }
        String serverPort = env.getProperty("server.port");
        String contextPath = env.getProperty("server.servlet.context-path");
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(contextPath)) {
            contextPath = "/";
        }
        String hostAddress = "localhost";
        try {
            hostAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            log.warn("The host name could not be determined, using `localhost` as fallback");
        }
        log.info(
                "\n----------------------------------------------------------\n\t" + "Application '{}' is running! Access URLs:\n\t"
                        + "Local: \t\t{}://localhost:{}{}\n\t" + "External: \t{}://{}:{}{}\n\t"
                        + "Profile(s): \t{}\n----------------------------------------------------------",
                env.getProperty("spring.application.name"), protocol, serverPort, contextPath, protocol, hostAddress, serverPort, contextPath,
                env.getActiveProfiles());
    }


}
```

**SpringCloudFunction**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

import org.apache.commons.collections.MapUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    
@Component("springCloudFunctionOne")
public class SpringCloudFunctionOne implements Function<Map<String, Object>, Map<String, Object>>{

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> apply(Map<String, Object> t) {    
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("status", "success");
        return response;
    }
}
```

Here is the AWS Lambda execution output

```
2024-03-26 14:46:35.588  INFO 8 --- [           main] o.s.nativex.NativeListener               : AOT mode enabled
.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
\\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
'  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
:: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.1)
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 10002.90 ms  Phase: init Status: timeout
2024-03-26 14:46:36.081  INFO 9 --- [           main] o.s.nativex.NativeListener               : AOT mode enabled
.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
\\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
'  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
:: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.1)
2024-03-26 14:46:36.114  INFO 9 --- [           main] c.g.c.CredentialingJobApplication        : Starting CredentialingJobApplication using Java 11.0.19 on 169.254.55.13 with PID 9 (/workspace/com.ghx.credentialing.CredentialingJobApplication started by sbx_user1051 in /workspace)
2024-03-26 14:46:36.114  INFO 9 --- [           main] c.g.c.CredentialingJobApplication        : The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
2024-03-26 14:46:36.240  WARN 9 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'enableEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'enableEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'encryptablePropertySourceConverter': Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid jasypt.encryptor.skip-property-sources: Class org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertySource not found
2024-03-26 14:46:36.283 ERROR 9 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Native reflection configuration for org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertySource is missing.
Action:
Native configuration for a class accessed reflectively is likely missing.
You can try to configure native hints in order to specify it explicitly.
See https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#native-hints for more details.
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 337.49 ms    Phase: invoke   Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.ExitError
START RequestId: 90bab59f-bb33-4346-b129-c3fd1da25e23 Version: $LATEST
RequestId: 90bab59f-bb33-4346-b129-c3fd1da25e23 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
END RequestId: 90bab59f-bb33-4346-b129-c3fd1da25e23
REPORT RequestId: 90bab59f-bb33-4346-b129-c3fd1da25e23  Duration: 338.37 ms Billed Duration: 339 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 35 MB
```